# How to add additional parameter to Request.ServerVariables.Get("ALL_HTTP")

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have to add some additional parameter in our `http header`. Suppose I use it must contain some  additional parameter by me and should be visible to everywhere. If any one use my http header all things should be visible along with my additional parameter. `Request.ServerVariables.Get("ALL_HTTP");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might add custom headers within web.config.
Example:

```
<configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                    <add name="CustomHeader1" value="Hi" />
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
        </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```